# C# Regex - words, spaces, numbers and special characters in any order

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, spaces, scrape

Here is an example of what information i'm trying to extract with regex

```
class="result-title hdrlnk">CHAVY IMPALA</a><span class="result-meta"><span class="result-price">$1300</span>


class="result-title hdrlnk">1950 Buick Super straight 8 with 3 on the tree</a><span class="result-meta"><span class="result-price">$9850</span>


class="result-title hdrlnk">Buick Lesabre Hardtop Coupe</a><span class="result-meta"><span class="result-price">$8800</span>
```

I was able to successfully get the price but I am having issues with getting the name of the listing for vehicles. Here is an example of the regex

This code works great for getting the price and additional brackets

```
Regex vg = new Regex(@"</a><span class=""result\-meta""><span class=""result-price"">\$\d+");
```

I've tried using the period at the beginning but that will only display the last letter or number of the listing title it will not display the entire listing title.

```
Regex vg = new Regex(@".</a><span class=""result\-meta""><span class=""result-price"">\$\d+");
```

I've also tried

```
Regex vg = new Regex(@">.*</a><span class=""result\-meta""><span class=""result-price"">\$\d+");
```

and

```
Regex vg = new Regex(@">\d+</a><span class=""result\-meta""><span class=""result-price"">\$\d+");
```

but no luck with the listing title :( Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One reason we never recommend parsing html and xml with REGEX,

Comment: Take a deep breath and look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2307070).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex [`class=\"result-title hdrlnk\">(.*?)<\/a><span class=\"result-meta\"><span class=\"result-price\">(.*?)<\/span>`](https://regex101.com/r/rkOcvw/1), preferably one listing at the time.

```
string input = "your input"
string pattern = @"class=\""result-title hdrlnk\"">(.*?)<\/a><span class=\""result-meta\""><span class=\""result-price\"">(.*?)<\/span>");
Match match = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
string title = match.Groups[1].Value;
string price = match.Groups[2].Value
```

Comment: @Fabio Alfara Please accept and deliver me from the devil reputation number

Comment: How do I go about doing so? Sorry I'm new here and I want to give you credit :)

Comment: You can click on the ✔ to accept and the up arrow to upvote.